# Static initialization vs Enum approach for Singleton pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, static, singleton

I am learning singleton design pattern from the head first design pattern book.

They have given one approach which uses static initialization. Static initialization is done at the time of class loading and the problem with this approach is that it will create the instance even if we are not using it(at the time of class loading) which means it will do `eager initialization`.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton uniqueInstance = new Singleton();

    // Other useful fields here (can be static or non-static)

    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

    // Other useful methods here (can be static or non-static)
}
```

They have given one more approach which uses an enum.

```
public enum Singleton {
    UNIQUE_INSTANCE;
 
    // other useful fields here (can be static or non-static)

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return UNIQUE_INSTANCE;
    }

    // other useful methods here (can be static or non-static)
}
```

I want to know what is the difference between the above approaches in terms of when the object is created(In both cases when we are using that object in the application and when we are not using the object throughout the application).

In other words, I want to know whether the enum approach will also do `eager initialization`?

Answer (score 0):

Enum objects are instantiated when the `enum` class loads.

So yes, you could consider that to be "eager initialization".

---

Using an `enum` to define a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in Java is the approach recommended by [Dr. Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) in his famous book, *Effective Java*.

Comment: This means both the above approaches are equivalent for singleton pattern and the enum approach will also do eager initialization?

Comment: @DeveshKumar Yes, enum constants are eagerly initialized. The two approaches are not strictly equivalent, however. An enum comes with more guarantees, like not being able to create more instances even through reflection or serialization (though I think `java.lang.invoke.*` can get around that restriction, or at least used to be able to).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks. Now I got enum is more powerful for Singleton

Answer (score 0):

When using an enum, the single constant is public. There's no need to add a getter for it.

As far as I'm concerned, only use an enum if you need any of its advantages. There aren't that many though, since comparison and switching is not relevant with only a single instance. There is one advantage I can think of (if you need it): enums are serializable. Getting serialization to work for non-enum singletons isn't trivial; you need to work with `readResolve` (and possibly `writeReplace`) to make sure that when the serialized singleton value is read from the steam, no new instance is returned. One is still created though, it will just be discarded. When using an enum you get serialization for free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It makes sense now for using an enum.